# How to find controls on a dynamically created user control in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, web-user-controls

I have to disable a link on dynamically created user control depending on condition.

How to find type of the control? 
I am using a placeholder, hence trying to find the control like below
`this.placeholder1.FindControl("usercontrol1").FindControl("div1");`

How to find link on usercontrol1 of type UserControl1?
I can't use the name UserControl1 of the .ascx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must recreate dynamic controls on each postback.
2. Then only you can access those control using

> var yourControll= (UserControlType)
>   this.placeholder1.FindControl("usercontrol1");

Comment: if i recreate the controls on postback will it not lose the post data that it holds?